# Multiplexing 12 sensors to be read with 6 ADC channels

Tags: adc, xbee, multiplexer

I'm buying [this Xbee chip](http://ie.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Digi-International/XB24-ASI-001/?qs=3NWcvBQo1qMIizVxVhDMt7T30vI%252bKWCntyTNYbV9Sek=).

But it only has 6 ADC pins and I have 12 sensors! Can I multiplex my 12 inputs? How hard is it to do this? I don't want to have to use 2 Xbee modules for power/cost reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a CD4051 8-to-1 analog multiplexer and connect it to one of your analog channels, which will give you a total of 13 channels.  You'll need 3 digital outputs to select the active channel on the multiplexer.

Comment: Very useful. Many thanks. I'll look up the CD4051.

Comment: thanks very useful chip ? CD4051. How much it cost over there?

Comment: @sandundhammika, You can answer questions like that at findchips.com.